# Pass reactive data from a shiny app to a script in Rstudio

Tags: r, shiny

I have found a way to call a shiny app within another shiny app like below.

**1.my initial app**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyML)

# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Upload File", multiple = FALSE, accept = c(".csv", ".xlsx", ".xls")),
      uiOutput("select"),
      actionButton("launch_app", "Launch second Shiny App")
      
    ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
    )
    
  )
)

# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$launch_app, {
    rstudioapi::jobRunScript(path = "C:/Users/User/Documents/Deniz3/script.r")
  })
  file_info <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    "xlsx" = readxl::read_excel(input$file1$datapath)
    
  })
  output$select<-renderUI({
    req(input$file1)
    selectInput("sel","select one column",choices = unique(colnames(file_info())),
                selected = unique(colnames(file_info()))[1],
                multiple = F)
  })
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**2.through this I call the **script.r****

```
shiny::runApp("C:/Users/User/Documents/Deniz3/SHINYML.R", launch.browser = TRUE, port = 875)
```

**3.and that calls another script **SHINYML.R** that includes the function that creates the new app**

```
library(shinyML)
# An example of regression task 
shinyML_classification(data = iris,y = "Species",framework = "h2o")
```

Now I want to be able to change the iris dataset and the `Petal.Length` that are used as inputs in my last script with my uploaded dataset and column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the intermediate file **script.R**.

The function `rstudioapi::jobRunScript` has an argument `importEnv`; if you set it to `TRUE`, the global environment is imported in the job. So set it to `TRUE` and in some observers, assign the uploaded dataframe and the chosen column to the global environment:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyML)

# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Upload File", multiple = FALSE, accept = c(".csv", ".xlsx", ".xls")),
      uiOutput("select"),
      actionButton("launch_app", "Launch second Shiny App")
      
    ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
    )
    
  )
)

# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$launch_app, {
    rstudioapi::jobRunScript(
      path = "C:/SL/ztemp/SHINYML.R",
      importEnv = TRUE
    )
  })
  
  file_info <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    readxl::read_excel(input$file1$datapath)
  })
  
  observeEvent(file_info(), {
    assign("uploadedData", file_info(), envir = .GlobalEnv)
  })
  
  output$select <- renderUI({
    req(file_info())
    selectInput("sel","select one column",choices = unique(colnames(file_info())),
                selected = unique(colnames(file_info()))[1],
                multiple = F)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$sel, {
    assign("chosenColumn", input$sel, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  })
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**SHINYML.R**:

```r
library(shinyML) 
shinyML_classification(data = uploadedData, y = chosenColumn, framework = "h2o")
```

*Note:* `shinyML_classification` fails if there's a white space in `y`!